# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel 5.1 Join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have three tables. `work_orders`, `customers`, and `aircraft`. In the `work_orders` table there are two fields `customer_id` and `aircraft_id`. I'm trying to retrieve the `customers` and `aircraft` data through the use of `join`. I am getting an array of errors, but they all seem to be pointed in the same direction and that is that the table cannot be found.

Here is my `WorkOrderController index`:

```
public function index(WorkOrder $workorder)
{
$workorder_array = $workorder
    ->join('work_orders as work', 'work.aircraft_id', '=', 'aircraft.id')
    ->join('work_orders as workorder', 'workorder.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->select('work_orders.opened_date', 'customers.mobile', 'aircraft.year')
    ->get();

return view('work-orders.index', compact('workorder_array'));
}
```

And with this I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'aircraft.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `work_orders`.`opened_date` from `work_orders` inner join `work_orders` as `work` on `aircraft`.`id` = `work`.`aircraft_id` inner join `work_orders` as `workorder` on `workorder`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`)

I've tried switching `work.aircraft_id` with `aircraft.id`, because the Laravel Docs show it in that order, but that doesn't make any difference either. The only way I can get rid of this error is to remove my `join` statements.

Comment: You can open console and run this sql query, if you get error check you field in you table and database, after you can try get right query. sorry for my English.

Comment: Just curious: Shouldn't `aircraft` suppose to be `aircrafts` ? Because, Laravel uses snake case convention for naming the tables. Unless you have explicitly specified the table name as `aircraft`..

Comment: I have specified it to be aircraft because that is the plural of airplane. I've been accessing that table from other places on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong table in the `join` statement. Here's what I should have had:

```
public function index(WorkOrder $workorder)
{
    $workorder_array = $workorder
        ->join('aircraft', 'work_orders.aircraft_id', '=', 'aircraft.id')
        ->join('customers', 'work_orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();

    return view('work-orders.index', compact('workorder_array'));
}
```